# Inconsistent behavior between seemingly identical if let blocks

Tags: swift, if-statement, option-type

I had this code in my `cellForRowAt` function:

```
if let modifiedDate = deliveryItem.modifiedDate?.toString(format: "M/d/yy"), let modifiedBy = deliveryItem.modifiedBy {
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text += "   (MODIFIED: \(modifiedDate) BY: \(modifiedBy))"
}
```

But it was skipping the inner line even when both properties had non-nil values.  On a whim, I tried moving the `toString` call to the inner line:

```
if let modifiedDate = deliveryItem.modifiedDate, let modifiedBy = deliveryItem.modifiedBy {
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text += "   (MODIFIED: \(modifiedDate.toString(format: "M/d/yy")) BY: \(modifiedBy))"
}
```

And suddenly it started working and producing the expected output.  The two pieces of code seem functionally identical as far as I can tell, so I don't understand why it wasn't working the first time.  I even tried running `deliveryItem.modifiedDate?.toString(format: "M/d/yy")` in the console just to make sure, and it returned a non-nil value.

Here is the `toString` function, but I don't see anything here that would affect unwrapping the value either:

```
extension Date {
    func toString (format: String?) -> String {
        guard let format = format else {
            return ""
        }

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

An example of data that should have passed:

```
modifiedDate = (Date?) 2018-10-05 23:50:00 UTC
modifiedBy = (String?) "SC"
```

Comment: Unrelated but displaying a date in the format `M/d/yy` to a user is a really bad idea. Many users are going to be confused. What does `10/8/18` mean? Is that Oct 8, 2018, Aug 10, 2018, or Aug 18, 2010? It's always best to show a date (and/or time) to a user using a date or time style, not a hardcoded format.

Comment: @rmaddy This is for a specific customer and that was the format they wanted.

Comment: Could you give examples of `deliveryItem.modifiedDate` and `deliveryItem.modifiedBy` where `cell.detailTextLabel?.text += ...` is not executed?

Comment: Unrelated but why is the `format` parameter optional? When you call the function you do want to convert the date to string and you would get an error at **compile** time if you are going to pass `nil`.

Comment: @Carpsen90 Added an example.  vadian, it's also used in another place where the format comes from an external source, and it was decided to return an empty string if the format was missing.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery both blocks pass for me. Please try [this](https://justpaste.it/1uqqc) code in a playground

Comment: Huh, after going back to it again I can't reproduce the original problem.  Must have been something messed up in Xcode.